# Nilpotent endomorphism and Jordan matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, nilpotence

I have a question about nilpotent endomorphism.

Suppose you have an endomorphism $N:V \rightarrow V$ which is nilpotent, such that the degree of nilpotency is equal to the dimension of $V$, i.e. $\dim V = \deg N$. 
Then the matrix which represents this nilpotent with ordered basis $v, Nv, N^2v .... N^{n-1}v$ is Jordan form of matrix. Actually that is a way of creating Jordan matrix for this endomorphism. My question is how to create this matrix when $\dim V$ is different from $\deg N$?

Comment: Google "core-nilpotent decomposition", "jordan normal form". In [*Matrix Analysis and Applied Linear Algebra*](http://www.matrixanalysis.com/), [Meyer](http://meyer.math.ncsu.edu/) finds the general jordan normal form by first finding the jordan normal form for nilpotent matrices and using the core-nilpotent decomposition to reduce the problem to nilpotent matrices.